# Understanding and Tuning the Linux Scheduler with PyTimeChart

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, embedded, scheduler

I have been doing some experiments to try and understand the CFS scheduler on an ARM based embedded system. In tests, I cannot see any change in behavior when I adjust the scheduler's parameters in sched_fair.c. My understanding is that processes should run for at least *sysctl_sched_min_granularity* before being preempted. Does anyone know why my threads run longer or shorter than this period given the following test setup?

Here are the relevent changes in sched_fair.c

```
/*
 * Targeted preemption latency for CPU-bound tasks:
 * (default: 5ms * (1 + ilog(ncpus)), units: nanoseconds)
 */
unsigned int sysctl_sched_latency = 20000000ULL; /* Changed from 5ms to 20ms */

/*
 * Minimal preemption granularity for CPU-bound tasks:
 * (default: 1 msec * (1 + ilog(ncpus)), units: nanoseconds)
 */
unsigned int sysctl_sched_min_granularity = 4000000ULL; /* Changed from 1ms to 4ms */

/*
 * SCHED_OTHER wake-up granularity.
 * (default: 1 msec * (1 + ilog(ncpus)), units: nanoseconds)
 *
 * This option delays the preemption effects of decoupled workloads
 * and reduces their over-scheduling. Synchronous workloads will still
 * have immediate wakeup/sleep latencies.
 */
unsigned int sysctl_sched_wakeup_granularity = 4000000UL; /* Changed from 1ms to 4ms */
```

For my test program I have a thread that sleeps, SLEEP_TIME_US defines how long.

```
#define SLEEP_TIME_US 1000
```

The 'DoNothing' thread sits in an infinite loop:

```
static void *DoNothing(void *)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
        ++i;
    return NULL;
}
```

The 'SleepThread' sits in an infinite loop and sleeps for some predetermined amount of time set by SLEEP_TIME_US.

```
static void *SleepThread(void *)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        ++i;
        usleep(SLEEP_TIME_US);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Functions to launch my threads:

```
void StartDoNothingThread()
{
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, &DoNothing, NULL);
}

void StartSleepThread()
{
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, &SleepThread, NULL);
}
```

The experiment:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    StartDoNothingThread();
    StartDoNothingThread();
    StartDoNothingThread();
    StartDoNothingThread();
    StartSleepThread();

    clock_t startCycles = clock();
    clock_t endCycles;
    double cpuTime;

    system("echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_enabled");
    system("echo '' > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace");
    system("echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_enabled");

    while (true)
    {
        endCycles = clock();
        cpuTime = ((double)(endCycles - startCycles))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        if (cpuTime > 1) // Quit after 1 sec
        {
            system("echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_enabled");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I can plot the output of ftrace using pyTimeChart, which shows me the context switches. What I don't completely understand, is why the scheduler switches out a task sooner/later than *sysctl_sched_min_granularity*.

When I **DON'T** run the sleep thread, by commenting out StartSleepThread(), each thread runs for 10ms. However, based on my scheduler settings I would have assumed each task would run for 4ms.

When I run the sleep thread and set SLEEP_TIME_US to 1000, each thread runs for 1ms.

When I run the sleep thread and set SLEEP_TIME_US to 500, each thread runs for 0.5ms.

[[pyTimeChart Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrit1.jpg)]

It has been brought to my attention that there maybe interplay between the CONFIG_HZ setting in my architectures defconfig and scheduling. I believe I am running tick-less kernel. Despite that I tried setting CONFIG_HZ to 1000, but changing it didn't appear to affect any of the thread execution times. Currently my CONFIG_HZ is set to 100. Let me know if I can add any clarification.

**Edit:**

With a bit more tinkering, I was able to get my kernel to tick once per ms. The problem was that Kconfig wasn't including Kconfig.hz. Finally, things started making more sense. For example, threads ran for at least shed_min_granularity and sched_latency was honored.

That is, until I reinserted my sleeping thread. When the sleeping thread is running the scheduler will only run tasks for the duration the sleep before switch to the next. This is on 2.6.32. On a newer kernel, 4.1, tasks always run for min_granularity even with the sleeping thread. I am stuck using 2.6.32 for other reasons, but I would still like to understand this discrepancy.

Comment: This is not C++. Leaving adding C tag as a minor task to you.